# I want to block all external traffic but allow internal traffic on a port 138

Tags: networking, security, firewall, port

As a security enhancement, I need to block all incoming external traffic to port 138. But I want to make sure that systems within the same network can still access or communicate over this port, meaning all internal traffic should be allowed. How can I do this using firewall or iptables in Linux?

Comment: To echo @Harrymc's answer, routers block all inbound requests from `wan` by default, unless UPnP is enabled _(it shouldn't be, as no secure implementation of UPnP exists - in lieu of UPnP, port redirects should be configured)_; is this for a specific machine or a router? If a machine, it would likely resemble: `iptables -A zone_wan_forward -p all --dport 138 -m comment --comment "Reject Forwarded WAN 138 → <device>" -j REJECT` ([man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html))

Answer (score 1):

To block access to port 138 from the internet, you need to block it at the router.

However, port 138 is never open by default. So unless you opened it yourself by
configuring port-forwarding on the router, everything should work by default
exactly as you want.